# Declaration of Priority Queue using greater and vector

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

Can anybody please explain what is the meaning of this declaration:

```
typedef pair<long long, int> PII;
priority_queue<PII, vector<PII>, greater<PII> > Q;
```

Is it to be treated as a priority queue of pair of `long long` and `int` or something else? Can please someone also explain what is `greater<PII>` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [priority queue implementation explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944305/priority-queue-implementation-explanation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declares a `std::priority_queue` containing `std::pair<long long, int>` instances where a `std::vector<std::pair<long long, int>>` is the underlying container of the priority queue (as it is a container adaptor).

The `std::greater<std::pair<long long, int>>` is used as the Comparator function object for the queue, checking whether the LHS pair is greater than the RHS pair. See below for a reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater

Answer (score 2):

Using `greater` here means that lower values are considered of higher priority and come out of the priority queue earlier. By default `less` is used, and higher values are higher priority.

Pairs are ordered lexicographically; (1, 3) comes before (2, 1) and after (1, 2).

Comment: @Alan Stokes Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This is way to create min heap in c++ .

```
typedef pair<long long, int> PII;
priority_queue<PII, vector<PII>, greater<PII> > Q;
```